# How do I export a response on postman to a clearly laid-out csv/xls file?

Tags: json, api, csv, postman

I am new to APIs and currently working on a project to analyse data from a job website, reed.co.uk. I am trying to export the data to a spreadsheet with the variable names as headers, rather than a json. A typical GET request, e.g.

curl --location --request GET 'https://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=accountant&location=london' \

Returns this:

```
"results": [
    {
        "jobId": 44137966,
        "employerId": 575264,
        "employerName": "REED",
        "employerProfileId": null,
        "employerProfileName": null,
        "jobTitle": "Management Accountant",
        "locationName": "Maidstone",
        "minimumSalary": 28000.00,
        "maximumSalary": 35000.00,
        "currency": "GBP",
        "expirationDate": "28/10/2021",
        "date": "21/09/2021",
        "jobDescription": " My client is looking to recruit an ambitious and commercially aware Management Accountant.&nbsp; Working closely with the Finance Director, you will provide accurate and timely management accounting information and reports in accordance with strict deadlines.&nbsp;  In addition, you will work closely with the finance team providing support on a daily basis. Please note:&nbsp; The standard hours of work are 7.00am to 3.45pm, Mo... ",
        "applications": 3,
        "jobUrl": "https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/management-accountant/44137966"
```

etc etc

If I then follow Postman's own method for writing to csv (https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/3407886/RWgp1fB5?version=latest) the resulting file only contains one row with all the data - if I do it with xls instead it is all put into a single cell. Ideally each column would contain the job variable (if that is the right term), e.g. JobId, employerId, employerName etc, and each row be a new job entry.

Reed's API documentation is here: https://www.reed.co.uk/developers/jobseeker.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't want to fix the existing api, so I write a new one.

**Step 1**: Install `json-2-csv`

```
npm install json-2-csv
```

**Step 2**: Add below code to file `script.js`

```
const converter = require("json-2-csv");

app.post("/toCsv", (req, res) => {
    let filename = `File_${Date.now()}`,
        filePath = `${path.join(folderPath, filename)}.csv`;

    converter.json2csv(req.body, (err, csv) => {
        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, csv);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send("Error");
        } else {
            res.send("Success");
        }
    });
});
```

**Step 3**: Start local app

```
node .\script.js
```

**Step 4**: Make request in postman inside tab `Tests`.

```
const list = pm.response.json().results;

const postRequest = {
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/toCsv',
  method: 'POST',
  header: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: {
    mode: 'raw',
    raw: JSON.stringify(list)
  }
};
pm.sendRequest(postRequest, (error, response) => {
  console.log(error ? error : response);
});
```

[image]

**Step 5**: Check the folder `Responses`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - a little stuck on step 4, do you mean that the url should be changed to http://localhost:3000/toCsv under edit->tests and then:
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/toCsv', ?

And in terms of making sure the body is an array, does that just mean making sure it remains a json file?

Comment: @philt About url, yes, I made a new API `/toCsv`, and kept `/write` as it was. About `array`, because the csv file will take the keys of object inside array as header of csv file, so the body must be an array.

Comment: @philt I've updated my answer. Making a request inside `Tests` tab in postman

Comment: Sorry I am quire new to Postman and node. could you explain what does " Start local app" mean by (step 3), please? I am using node.js comman prompt and get into the directoy where script.js file is located. When running "node .\script.js", I got an error saying "ReferenceError: app is not defined" Could you help me plz?

Comment: @blackbeaans some steps you may miss https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/3407886/RWgp1fB5?version=latest

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17, in step 3 of " documenter.getpostman.com/view/3407886/RWgp1fB5?version=latest",I should install "install json-2-csv" (where to be located the script.js file) then, step 4 in above docuemnt corresponds to your step3, right? I am kind of not able to test it now and wanted to know if these are correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @blackbeaans I'm afraid not. My answer based on the project https://github.com/sivcan/ResponseToFile-Postman.  You need to clone it first then edit `script.js` file in this project.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17, Thanks! I managed to run and get csv files but it doesn't have any content. The weird thing is that i get json file when running  in "Params" tab and running "Test" tab with your Step 4, create csv but without content. Any mistake that you suspect?
Your coding in Step 2 should be added in the last line of the exising script.js? or should be in the middle?

Comment: @blackbeaans I'm not sure why but I guess the problem is request body. My code requires Request body must be an array of object. E.g `[{"id":1,"foo":"bar1"},{"id":2,"foo":"bar2"}]`. My code in Step 2 can be anywhere in script.js, I put it in the last line.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17, That's right. My json file has a bit different structre (a bit more nested) like {"data": [ {"id": "186-2022-05-19","type": "real_asset_day","attributes": {"date": "2022-05-19",...} I will figure out a roundabout in python. But thanks a lot for all your support, lucas!